# python opencv get all pixels with exact same value on each colour channel

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image in OpenCV, that I would like to convert to a binary array.

I would like each pixel with identical BGR colour values to be 1, for example #FFFFFF would be white but #FFE0A1 would be black as all three channels do not share the same value.

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use masking to do this. For example,

```
import numpy as np

# random image
img = (np.random.randn(1000, 1000, 3) * 255).astype(np.uint8)

img[0, 0] = np.array([255, 255, 255]) # test value

# initialization of binary image with all zeros
binary = np.zeros((img.shape[:-1]), dtype=int)

# create boolean masks
a = img[:, :, 0] == img[:, :, 1]
b = img[:, :, 1] == img[:, :, 2]

# this will create the final mask (a and b)
mask = np.logical_and(a, b)

# make the final assignment
binary[mask] = 1
```

Then, if you check `binary`,

```
>>> binary
    array([[1, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
           ...,
           [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0],
           [0, 0, 0, ..., 0, 0, 0]])
```

As you can see, the test value turned out to be correctly assigned to `1`.

Comment: This looks like it could be exactly what I need, thanks.

Comment: I am having trouble using the `cv2.imshow()` on the binary array created from your code, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @elite gamer88 The data type should be `uint8`